# Tabs in content with ion-segment ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'am new as ionic developer. I can't develop tabs with a look like ion-segment (as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R3Cs.png)) because the app is build for Android and ion-segment are for iOS. Is there a workaround to do it for Android apps? Help me please.

Comment: ion-segment is in ionic version 2 and higher. Use ion segment under ion-toolbar in the header. Refer here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/

Comment: yes i use this methode. i want excactly script css to customize ion-segment to get toolbar in  image